# Differential equation from a chemistry problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this differential equation:

$$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} = k_1\big(a-(x-c)\big)\big(b-(x-c)\big) - k_2(x)$$

The equations is from a chemical problem, but I don't now how to solve it. Should I try to simplify it, or can I attack it right away?

Comment: Are $k_1, k_2$ constants?

Comment: yes they are! @Travis

Comment: Are you trying to *solve* this differential equation or simply to compute the limit of the solution when $t\to\infty$? In applications, the latter is often the only parameter of interest.

Comment: @Did I dont really know, the assignment says: determine the differential equation for this case and solve it!

Comment: This seems an absurd task, unless the parameters $(k_1,k_2,a,b,c)$ are explicit.

Comment: @Did How can i solve it if i assume they are explicit?

Answer (score 4):

Hoping that I properly read the equation $$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} = k_1\Big(a-(x-c)\Big)\Big(b-(x-c)\Big) - k_2 x$$ it is separable and reduces to $$\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx} =\frac {1}{Ax^2-Bx+C}$$ with $A=k_1$,$B={k_1} (a+b+2 c)+{k_2}$,$C={k_1} (a+c) (b+c)$ and then $$t+K=\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 A x-B}{\sqrt{4 A C-B^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{4 A C-B^2}}$$ and then $$x=\frac{\sqrt{4 A C-B^2} \tan \left(\frac{1}{2} (K+t) \sqrt{4 A C-B^2}\right)+B}{2 A}$$

**Added later**

As Did pointed out, I did not check if $4 A C-B^2 > 0$. If fact, this quantity is always negative. Replacing and expanding gives $$4 A C-B^2=-2 {k_1} {k_2} (a+b+2 c)-{k_1}^2 (a-b)^2-{k_2}^2$$ So, the solution involves the $\tanh ^{-1}$ what I definitely prefer for a kinetic problem.$$x=\frac{B-\sqrt{B^2-4 A C} \tanh \left(\frac{1}{2} (K+t) \sqrt{B^2-4 A C}\right)}{2 A}$$

Comment: Why is $4AC-B^2$ nonnegative?

Comment: @Did. Not only it is a good question but it is always negative (assuming that $a,b,c,k_1,k_2$ are all positive ! So the solution involves $\tanh ^{-1}$ which I definitely prefer !

Comment: Okey, what is K?

Comment: Integration constant to be fixed say for $x(0)$

Answer (score 0):

This differential equation can be solved with [separation of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables). Eliminate the brackets, then you have a differential equation of the form

$$f'(x) = a x^2 + bx + c$$

The integral might become a little tricky, but will have an analytic solution (either an arctan or a artanh/arcoth function).